# Data augmentation in bioacoustics: pros and cons?

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, data-augmentation

Even though we already have a discussion regarding what kind of data augmentation makes sense for ML in bioacoustics ([Data augmentation strategies for bioacoustics machine learning](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/98/data-augmentation-strategies-for-bioacoustics-machine-learning)), i believe it would be helpful to list out some pros and cons of using data augmentation at all?

(initially asked by Julie Oswald at the Full-stack Bioacoustics workshop in Leyden)

Comment: Hi Iostanlen, welcome to stack exchange! To make your question more different from the existing question you mentioned, what about focusing on the cons only? I have the impression that the advantages are already given in the mentioned thread, aren't they?

Comment: the mentioned question asks about the how. i'm asking about the why (and why not).

Comment: Oh okk! Sorry for the misguidance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what i have so far.

Pros:

- no extra labeling required
- some software libraries make it very easy for you these days. See muda, specaugment, audiomentations
- you can listen to the result to check if you're doing things right (if you can't recognize the sound after augmentation, it means it's too harsh and you should reparametrize it so it retains recognizability)
- at the end of the day, it's the same model architecture, just trained differently. so the time/memory budget at prediction time is the same.
- it almost always improves performance, and it's easy to understand why

Cons:

- the task is more difficult, so convergence is slower at training time, so you need to iterate more through the augmented dataset than through the original dataset, so you're going need to plan for a longer training time
- be careful not to go overboard with it. as i wrote above, if your data augmentation is so harsh that it jeopardizes the recognizability of the sound, it won't work

Additional answers/comments are welcome :)